# Bitcoin contracts. Are there good examples in the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, script, contracts

I have been checking the Bitcoin wiki for script and Bitcoin contracts and I have some doubts about advanced contracts.

For instance, I have seen in many places references to password controlled transfers, where only the owner of a keyword could get the BTC in the contract. Do you know of any example in the blockchain? I am curious about anything with script commands beyond the standard use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advanced contracts are hardly used currently, if at all - simply because the software to construct the necessary transactions has not been written yet. I doubt you will find examples on the blockchain.

Comment: There might be some examples referenced here: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/2803/153

Comment: The multiple signature example in the link is similar to what I was looking for. From the linked post, I guess that using script should be possible, but, in practice, it is seldom used as miners won't include them in their blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm closing this question. I have found a nice tool to look for non-standard scripts:

https://github.com/gavinandresen/bitcointools

With:
  dbdump.py --search-blocks=NONSTANDARD_CSCRIPTS
I can check the kind of transactions I am curious about.

There are some interesting things there and I will spend some time looking into all, but, as a whole, there are few complex contracts (a few miners accept them). I will take Meni Rosenfeld's answer as the accepted answer.