# Promise-to-pay functionality without escrow where sellers vote if they should pay

Tags: escrow

Is there a promise-to-pay functionality with no escrow where a seller can set a bitcoin address for buyers to send promise-to-pay bitcoins. Once seller fulfills his promise, the buyers will confirm theirs: if 50% or more of the buyers confirm their promise, seller gets the money.

Example: An author promises to write a book if readers pay him N bitcoins.
Once author's account has N or more promise-to-pay bitcoins author publishes book.
Once 50% (this percentage can be adjusted) or more payees confirm the money goes to the author.

Comment: Title ,.... did you mean "buyers" not "sellers"?

Comment: Remove the last sentence, since it was wrong and misleading: the whole point of such a service is _because_ the author doesn't (can't!) trust buyers to hold to their promise. And it works _despite_ that.

Answer (score 3):

That is referred to as M of N transactions.  So you have 6 buyers, and at least three must agree to the transaction for the funds to be delivered to the seller.

It's coming.

- [Why are m-of-n transactions not used today?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2802)